# No puedo conectarme de forma remota a mi BD

Tags: mysql

en mi servidor tengo este usuario:

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| jose             | %         |
+------------------+-----------+
```

Luego intento conectarme desde mi PC en windows con **workbench**.

Al intentarlo me arroja este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero he indicado expresamente que el usuario jose pueda ser accedido desde cualquier lado. Que puede estar pasando ?

Los puertos y todo esta bien, uso docker y todo esta bindeado.

Answer (score 0):

¿estas seguro de haber configurado tu MySQL en ese puerto?, regularmente se utiliza el puerto 3306 o 3307, utiliza esta consulta

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port';
```

para que te de como resultado el puerto actual, si te devuelve el puerto que estas colocando entonces has un ping desde cmd hacia esa pc, si no puedes hacerlo es tu conexion con esa PC.
Si dices que asignaste acceder a tu usuario de una pc remota, refresca los privilegios con: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: Si, el puerto es el 3306

Comment: Si es ese puerto entonces estas colocando mal tu ip para conectarte, intenta poner 192.168.0.10:3306 en lugar de el puerto 39939 que estas colocando

Comment: eso se conectaria a mi bd del NAS, quiero conectarme a la IP del contenedor, que le he asignado a la ip que he puesto